# How to update zfproject.xml file after deleting some controllers, dbtables, etc. in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans

I am using Netbeans IDE to work with Zend Framework. When I create a new controller, action, etc.. using Netbeans Zend Command Window, zfproject.xml file is updated automatically. However, when I delete some of them, the file is not updated and still keeps the names that I deleted.

1. Is there a way (apart from manual way) to update this file?
2. Is it needed to update zfproject.xml to run the project properly or is it just an organized schema of the project?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think this is a question about Netbeans and has nothing to do with Zend Framework. You should adjust the title and retag your question then it will find the right persons to answer your question.

Comment: I think that zend studio will manage that for you... but AFAIK the only thing that its really needed for is Zend_Tool (IMO Zend_Tool is worthless anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very good question. `zfproject.xml` often gets out of sync when you use both Zend Tool and manual creating of the files.

> Is there a way (apart from manual way) to update this file?

I don't know a good answer for this part. You may try to iterate the application directory structure.

> Is it needed to update zfproject.xml to run the project properly or is it just an organized schema of the project?

This is just a schema which is not parsed during the normal application life. Used only by the tools.